# Fullscreen Video Tearing on Ubuntu 14.10 (Haswell Graphics)

Tags: video, google-chrome, html5, tearing

Over the past few weeks, I have noticed that I've had video tearing issues in Google Chrome on YouTube (and such other sites) with the video tearing when I put it on fullscreen. It might be an issue with HTML5 players, but I'm not sure. I can't remember if this problem was present in Ubuntu 14.04 or not.

Comment: I've seen this issue occasionally on 14.04 on Chromium with patches to enable VA-API on Linux. I suspect it's a problem somewhere between Intel graphics and the browser. Just to check, do you also see flashes of the browser window when viewing videos?

Comment: Nope. No flashes of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was happening on Ubuntu 16.04 on my Macbook Pro. I solved it with these steps:

```
 sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then go to General -> Composite and uncheck "Unredirect Fullscreen Windows". Best of luck!